# Pulling private github repo set as dependency in package.json within docker generated failing in github actions

Tags: git, docker, github, package.json, github-actions

**Expected behavior:**  
Github actions pipeline is triggered which then proceeds to build a docker image out of a dockerfile. 
This dockerfile contains an npm install step that installs required packages listed in a package.json file. 
One of the dependencies is a private github repo so it is required using the following format:

```
"packageName": "git+https://<auth token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/orgName/packageName.git"
```

It should be installed without any issues and keep going with the dockerfile build process 
**Issue:** 
The dockerfile builds without issues locally but when I try to build it using github actions it outputs the following error :

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/orgName/packageName.git
npm ERR! error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
```

***Notes:*** 
The whole docker image build process runs without issue locally so I really do not think it is a docker issue and more of a github restriction issue

Answer (score 1):

If this works locally, check if your local `git config -l` includes any `insteadOf` directive, like:

```
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"
```

If so, check your GitHub workflow in order to include that configuration, as in [`mvdan/github-actions-golang`](https://github.com/mvdan/github-actions-golang#how-do-i-install-private-modules) for instance:

> It's possible to install modules from private GitHub repositories without using your own proxy.
> You'll need to add a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) as a secret environment variable.
>
> ```yaml
> - name: Configure git for private modules
>  env:
>    TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
>  run: git config --global url."https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME:${TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"
> ```

Comment: I tried these but they did not affect the outcome, what i meant by locally was building the docker locally so shouldn't docker provide the consistent environment in this case since i am  using the same images and commands both in local docker build and in github actions?

Comment: also a small thing to note is that in the logs of the github actions github usually censors details with *** so in my case it censored  the command as `` url."***github.com/ `` so i am not sure if that might be related to the issue. (there was no  insteadOf in the original git config)

Comment: @charbelk Can you test https://github.com/oznu/docker-homebridge/issues/283#issuecomment-606522357? Maybe the docker version used in the GitHub Action is not the same as on your computer? (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2771#issuecomment-308652143) Or a cache issue (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2771#issuecomment-308831139)